# Do I have to have one wallpaper file for each screen resolution?

Tags: android, screen-resolution, wallpaper

There is an app that sets 960x800 image as phone's wallpaper. I found that many developers suggest this resolution. However, an image is still getting cropped. I use a basic code for setting the wallpaper

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
wallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.some_image);
```

I need an advice on what to do next:

1. Make one wallpaper for each screen resolution?
2. Programmatically resize image to a current screen resolution?
3. I am using the wrong code and there is a better one

If the second choice is the right solution, how should I do it? I'd appreciate some links if there's too much coding involved.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a 9-patch image for backgrounds, wallpapers are the same I think. Google docs on Android recommend this. This image is stretchable. A good link explaining it is [here](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/).

Comment: I am aware of 9.png, but I did not know I can use it for bg. If it works, I will mark your reply as answer.

Comment: It did not solve the problem for wallpaper. It is still stretched. Maybe I made 9-patch in a non-correct way, but it did not work.

Comment: It should, look at here (http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=1882) about how to save and use 9-patch images. We use it and it works. Also google for using 9-patch as backgrounds. It is a fairly common solution.

Comment: I have to be more precise. I do not need it for background of the `View`. Were you referring to this? I need it as a wallpaper on the mobile desktop (just like live wallpaper, but a regular wallpaper)

Comment: Now that is different story :) I dont know how that works on desktops. Sorry, I am out of my league there. Good luck on this though.

Comment: I made a 9.png image with the lowest resolution and I think it works this way. :)